# listbox itemContainer only contains border

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a delete button in my list's datatemplate that will appear only when the user clicks a button in the application bar . i am using the visual tree to access the elements inside listcontainer but it shows that the item container only has a border element and nothing else 
here is my datatemplate xaml

```
 <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel>
         <Grid>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="0" Height="auto" Width="auto" FontSize="50"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Height="auto" Width="auto" FontSize="50" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
             <Image  Name="del" Source="/Assets/AppBar/delete.png" Grid.Column="4" Tap="delete_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding}"/>
         </Grid>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" Height="auto" Width="auto" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
     </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

and here is the visual tree code

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var items in notes.Items)
    {
        var x = notes.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(items);
        var p = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(x);
        MessageBox.Show(p.ToString());
    }
}
```

the getchildrencount is always 1 and that is the border . how can i access the image from code?

Comment: Why don't you put that Button in the DataTemplate make a binding to its Visibility Property and changed that Binding to Visible when the AppBarIcon is pressed?

Comment: i tried to do that . The listbox has list of object notes set to as its datacontext how do i set the datacontext of the the image seperately?? .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7). This describes how to pick a control that is placed inside a ListBox item.

(or)

A better solution to your problem could be:

1. Create a boolean property in your ViewModel and initialize it with false.
2. Have the Delete button in the DataTemplate itself and set Delete Button's DataContext as your ViewModel (each UIElement will have it's own DataContext property, so you can set for Button separately and it will override ListBox DataContext).
3. Bind Visibility property of the Delete Button to the boolean property defined in the ViewModel (use Converter to change bool value to Visibility value).
4. When the user clicks on the application bar, set the boolean variable to true.